# How to append to CXXFLAGS in Makefile without editing Makefile?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, gnu-make, qmake

I'm writing a build script for a Qt application. The script first calls `qmake` on the .pro file and then runs `make CXXFLAGS=-DSWVERSION=xxxx`.

The problem with this is that it overwrites the CXXFLAGS already defined in the Makefile. Currently, the only method I know to solve this problem is to edit the Makefile and change this:

```
CXXFLAGS      = <flags>
```

To this:

```
CXXFLAGS      += <flags>
```

I was hoping there would be a simpler solution. Is there any way I can simply append to CXXFLAGS from the command line WITHOUT rewriting the Makefile?

Alternatively, my real problem is defining `SWVERSION` at build-time (because it is dependent on the build timestamp). Do you know of a better way to define this at runtime instead of passing it to CXXFLAGS?

Comment: An alternative to what you have now, instead as part of your make process you can generate a `swversion.h` file that has a single line `#define SWVERSION xxxx` in it, and have the relevant source file `#include "swversion.h"`.  My own preference is the `-DSWVERSION=xxxx` as you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this in the future, the solution I found was to call `qmake <project file> DEFINES+="SWVERSION=xxxx"`. Hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The change you suggest won't work anyway: a value set on the command line completely overrides the value set in the makefile, even if the value is appended to with `+=`.  You could do this and it would work:

```
override CXXFLAGS += <flags>
```

However, the way it's *normally* done is that the makefile provides variables which are reserved specifically for users to override on the command line.  For example in automake-generated makefiles, the common variables like `CXXFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, etc. are reserved for users to set via the command line or environment, and the internal makefile flags are put into a different variable, like `AM_CFLAGS`.  Then the recipes to compile objects uses both variable, like `$(CC) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) ...`

I don't know anything about qt so I can't say whether they have a similar set of reserved makefile variables but you might check the qt docs, or your generated makefile recipes, to see.

Comment: In Qt this would be [QMAKE_CXXFLAGS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html). So on your command line, you could probably do something like `CXXFLAGS='<flag> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS'`.

Comment: It would have to be `CXXFLAGS='<flag> $(QMAKE_CXXFLAGS)'`, not just `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`.  But, if done correctly, you don't add it at all.  Instead _both_ variables are used in the recipe, so they don't need to refer to each other.  But I don't know anything about qt-generated makefiles.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the responses. I looked into the generated Makefile, and it doesn't look like it includes any user-reserved variables. However, I did manage to solve this issue by calling qmake with `DEFINES+="SWVERSION=xxxx"`.